# What is the equivalent of logical negation/not operator

Tags: excel, vba, operators, negation

I've to execute a piece of code written in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) when the excel cell is *not* empty. I've written below piece of code so far:

```
Public Sub BindTitles(ByVal cell As Range)
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'other code
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to invert the logical condition present in `If` statement. In C#, I use [exclamation operator `!`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/logical-negation-operator) but when I put it in `If` block it gives below error:

> Compile error:
>
> Invalid or unqualified reference

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then ...`

Comment: You can use the `NOT` Operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/not-operator

Comment: Thanks @KostasK. It worked. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @KostasK. do you mind adding an answer so that I can close this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical negation `!` operator in VBA is `Not`:

```
If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then '...
```